# Set a condition inside React useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
const [o, setO] = useState(data === 'test' ? {name: "bill", age: 3} : {});
```

Is the statement above valid or should I use useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data === 'test') {
    setO(myObj)
  } else {
    setO({})
}, []);
```

Which is better? If the first one is correct does setting condition inside useState have a side effect or not?

Comment: where does data come from? prop?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, is just another state that is set when a user is clicking. Is not a prop

Comment: if it's a state that changes, then it should be in useEffect. If you want it to be updated whenever parent updates `data`, then you can add `data` to dependency array as well.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, why it should be in useEffect?

Comment: This doesn't need to be in state at all, keep `data` in state and create the appropriate object as a regular variable. If it becomes expensive, add useMemo. Your first snippet certainly won't work if data changes, because only the _first_ default value passed to useState matters. But it looks like you're letting test setup bleed into the actual implementation, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Go for useEffect. As it will set the state after mounting ui.
By setting state in useState there will be effect until you setState to change your state